# How to launch the browser with specific URL from Java Card 2.2.2 SIM card applet?

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard, sim-card, sim-toolkit

I am trying to build an application where my app sends an APDU to a Java Card applet on my SIM card. When this apdu is recieved I want my Applet to launch the browser with a specific URL. I can do the same in Java Card 3.0 Connected edition. I have read that Java Card 2.2.2 has a option in the proactive handler for launching browser, but I cannot find it. I would really appreciate if someone could show me how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. However, a lot of phones (especially those running iOS) do not support this, so you should always check the output of the `TERMINAL PROFILE` command first.

```
import sim.toolkit.*;
...

private final static byte[] URL = {
  (byte)'h', (byte)'t', (byte)'t', (byte)'p', (byte)':', (byte)'/', (byte)'/', (byte)'w', (byte)'w', (byte)'w', (byte)'.', (byte)'g', (byte)'o', (byte)'o', (byte)'g', (byte)'l', (byte)'e', (byte)'.', (byte)'c', (byte)'o', (byte)'m'
};
private static final byte PROFILE_LAUNCH_BROWSER = (byte)70;

private static final void browse() throws ToolkitException {
    if (MEProfile.check(PROFILE_LAUNCH_BROWSER)) { //checking if the device supports this proactive command
        ProactiveHandler proactiveHandler = ProactiveHandler.getTheHandler();
        proactiveHandler.init(ToolkitConstants.PRO_CMD_LAUNCH_BROWSER, (byte)0x00, ToolkitConstants.DEV_ID_ME);
        proactiveHandler.appendTLV(ToolkitConstants.TAG_URL, URL, (short)0, (short)URL.length);
        proactiveHandler.send();
    } else {
        //feature not supported, throw an exception or do something like that
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It appears that you have you proactive Handler. Which responds on an action from the SIM Toolkit applet. Can we rut this method when the SIM is powered up ?

Comment: @AbhirupGhosh Sorry, I don't understand your comment.... I use standard `ProactiveHandler`, which is usually available on SIM cards running Java Card. When would you like to initiate the proactive command? After some event? Or as a reaction to a direct SEEK API call?

Comment: Can I initiate it every time the sim is powered up without any interaction from the ME ?

Comment: @AbhirupGhosh You could register your applet for some event (e.g. EVENT_FIRST_COMMAND_AFTER_ATR) and start the proactive command on this event.